# Read an array of characters from space separated values

Tags: java

Is there an easy way in Java to convert space separated values to char array.

Example: "a b c" must become ['a','b','c'];

I tried

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] letters = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" "))
                       .map(a->a.charAt(0)).toArray();
```

, but this returns an Object[] instead of char[], so it doesn't work.

I know I can do it this way:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] line = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
          if(line[i]!=' '){
              letters.add(line[i]);
          }
    }
```

But I was wondering is there a more direct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that streams are not thought to handle primitives type like `char` or `byte`. The only primitives type that you can handle by default are int, long and double. So, if you want use streams and lambdas you have to switch to the Object version for each type which is in your case the `Character` object.

`toArray()` method returns an array of object, you have to use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` which returns a `ArrayList`.

```
List<Character> collect = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" "))
                       .map(a -> new a.charAt(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is very helpful :)

Comment: :) Thanks. The handling of primitive types with streams creates few subtle difference compared with the classic flow that sometimes make the life hard

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
char[] letters = scanner.nextLine().replace(" ", "").toCharArray();
```

See [KISS Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 1):

Why simply using your solution with a simple extension to remove the whitespaces?:

```
char[] letters = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("\s","").toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating from your code using a stream, you could use a `Collector` to build a `List`:

```
ArrayList<Character> letters = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" "))
                   .map(a->a.charAt(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, in case you are using or willing to use the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) utility library, you could find [`Splitter`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) useful in place of the `split` method (although it does not directly solve your specific problem).

Comment: They want an array not a list (although I don't know why)

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with an Array of `Character[]` type, you can use this method:

```
Character[] letters = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" ")).map(a -> a.charAt(0)).toArray(Character[]::new);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with `char[]::new`, so if you need to have the primitive `char[]` type, you have to convert the array to `char[]` afterwards. You can either use Apache Commons Lang's method

```
ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(letters);
```

or do this yourself

```
char[] a = new char[letters.length];
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    a[i] = letters[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
char[] letters = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(""))
                       .toCharArray();
```

But I'd probably use a Guava [`CharMatcher`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
char[] letters = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.removeFrom(scanner.nextLine())
                                       .toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your key issue here is that `Stream` is inherently a stream of objects, not primitives.

There is are parallel types `IntStream`, `LongStream`, `DoubleStream` but there is no `CharStream`.

You might decide that using `int` instead of `char` is enough for you, and you could do that with:

```
 int[] letters = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" "))
                   .mapToInt( a-> (int) a.charAt(0))
                   .toArray();
```

Note that this is good enough for the designers of the Java library: `String.chars()` returns an `IntStream`.

Alternatively you could:

- write your own `Collector`
- or convert the `int[]` to `char[]` as a separate step
- or just use String.toCharArray()